# Time taken to collide

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, gravity, celestial-mechanics

Two point masses **m1** and **m2**, separated initially by distance **d**, move towards each other under mutual gravitational force.
Find the time they take to collide?

The main problem I'm having is to solve the differential equation...

Comment: Here acceleration would be the function of  distance and you have to express them in term of distance.time will have relation with the distance change .

Comment: Because these are point masses, this problem has no solution, because at $r=0$ you hit a singularity: $F_1=F_2=+\infty$.

Comment: But to find the distance as a function of time, i.e. $r(t)$, use Conservation of Energy. Derive it to $t$ and you'll get a Newtonian EoM.

Comment: Related: [Gravitational attraction as distance approaches zero](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/565116/gravitational-attraction-as-distance-approaches-zero)